# When I address to HTML it makes attribute error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to address to HTML tag and then get the attribute, my code:

```
findPosition(target: HTMLDivElement): IPiece {
  const row: number = parseInt((HTMLDivElement).parentElement.getAttribute('row'));
  const column: number = parseInt((HTMLDivElement).parentElement.getAttribute('column'));
  const position: IPosition = { row, column };
  const pieceInstance = this.piecePlace[row][column]; 

  return { position, instance: pieceInstance };
}
```

and in this case `parseInt((HTMLDivElement).parentElement.getAttribute('row'))` I have such a problem:

> Property 'parentElement' does not exist on type '{ new (): HTMLDivElement; prototype: HTMLDivElement; }'.ts(2339)

How to handle it?

Comment: you should be using the variable `target` not it's type `HTMLDivElement`

Comment: @phuzi then I have new error: Object is possibly 'null'.

Comment: That sounds more like a warning than an error!

Answer (score 0):

Use target instead of HTMLDivElement

```
findPosition(target: HTMLDivElement): IPiece {
  const row: number = parseInt((target).parentElement.getAttribute('row'));// this line
  const column: number = parseInt((target).parentElement.getAttribute('column'));// this line
  const position: IPosition = { row, column };
  const pieceInstance = this.piecePlace[row][column]; 

  return { position, instance: pieceInstance };
}
```

Comment: then I have new error: Object is possibly 'null'.

Comment: When I use target instead HTMLDivElement I get an error

Comment: try use defaul value, ex:  parseInt((target).parentElement.getAttribute('row')|| 0); and parseInt((target).parentElement.getAttribute('column')||0)

Comment: it still doesn't work(
Argument of type 'string | 0' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)

Comment: use 2 charact | between 2 value. to more sure replace 0 by '0'. full will be: parseInt((target).parentElement.getAttribute('row')|| '0');